# Как сделать самодописывающийся массив Python?

Tags: python, массивы

Хотел сделать самподописывающийся массив,но после ввода дописывается только максимум 1 индекс
Мой код:

```
while True:
        array = ['Python','Array','Code']
        input_function = input("")
        array.append(input_function)
        print(array)

Output:
['Python', 'Array', 'Code', 'Lock']
```

Желаемый результат:

```
Output:['Python', 'Array', 'Code', 'Lock','Tree']
```

Comment: Вы в цикле каждый раз создаёте новый массив, поэтому все введённые значения уничтожаются. Просто перенесите создание массива перед циклом

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас в начале цикла список возвращается в предыдущее состояние.

```
while True:
    array = ['Python','Array','Code']
```

Решением будет просто вынести обозначение списка вне цикла.

```
array = ['Python','Array','Code']
while True:
    input_function = input("")
    array.append(input_function)
    print(array)
```